# Different Database on same crystal report

Tags: c#, sql-server, oracle, crystal-reports

I am running a Visual Studio application from two different databases SQL Server and Oracle.

I have created Crystal Reports using SQL Server. Now I want to run the same reports both for SQL Server and Oracle database servers. Can I do it from c# code behind? Can I change the datasource both for Oracle and SQL Server?

Answer (score 0):

why you are generating report from direct to database, you should set datasource by c# code. if you set datasource by code then crystal report no need Database. like below is example.

like you have a  employee collection.

```
public ICollectionView Employee  { get; set; }

EmployeeReport reportClass =new EmployeeReport ();

Employee = CollectionViewSource.GetDefaultView(emp);
```

//calling report method

```
DisplayReport(reportClass ,Employee ,"Test Company name","Employee List");
```

//method for display report

```
   public static void DisplayReport(ReportClass reportClass, object Employee, string companyName, string reportHeader)
    {
        reportClass.SetDataSource(source);
        var viewer = new ReportViewer();

        if(companyName != null)
            reportClass.SetParameterValue("txtCompanyName", companyName);

        if(reportHeader != null)
            reportClass.SetParameterValue("Header", reportHeader);

        viewer.SetReportSource(reportClass);

        viewer.ShowDialog();
    }
```